# Add keys using recurssive

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "my_obj": [
        {
            "qte": [
                {
                    "qte1": "2",
                    "somthing": "toto"
                },
                {
                    "qte1": "1",
                    "somthing": "tata"
                }
            ]    
        },
        {
            "qte": [
                {
                    "qte1": "77"
                },
                {
                    "somthing": "titi"
                }
            ]    
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add all keys "qte1" using recursion or some function nodeJs that do that and the get something like:

```
{
    "sumQte" : 80

}
```

Best regards

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to do it using recurssion

Comment: Can you reformat your question code to provide **exact** examples of your input and desired output?  I am not sure at the moment what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I think that is clear. I need just to add all  keys "qte1"

Comment: You're getting downvotes and close-votes because you haven't shown your own attempts. Right now, it reads as if you want somebody else to do your work for you. If you show us what you've tried and how it fails, we can guide you towards a solution instead of handing over the code you need...

Comment: I think that you aren't understand what I mean. I can easily solve this question using two loops in the two tables. But what I need to khnow is there is an elegant solution to do the same work.

Comment: @user3297291 , if you don't have the answer keep your comments for you. This web site is for all people(beginner advanced ...) there are many people that post questions, pretty straight, because they just started learning some language or for another reasons

Comment: Answering and commenting have different purposes. I was trying to help, not trying to offend you. I meant to encourage you to show your code and current approach, so people can better help explain what differs in a recursive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can solve this problem of yours. This is probably not optimal..

```
const test = {
      "my_obj": [
          {
              "qte": [
                  {
                      "qte1": "2",
                      "somthing": "toto"
                  },
                  {
                      "qte1": "1",
                      "somthing": "tata"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "qte": [
                  {
                      "qte1": "77"
                  },
                  {
                      "somthing": "titi"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  };
  let sum = 0;
  test.my_obj.map(obj => {
    obj.qte.map(obj2 =>{
      if(obj2.qte1 != null){
      sum+=parseInt(obj2.qte1);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {"my_obj":[{"qte":[{"qte1":"2","somthing":"toto"},{"qte1":"1","somthing":"tata"}]},{"qte":[{"qte1":"77"},{"somthing":"titi"}]}]};

function getQte1(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Array) { // if this is an array
    var sum = 0;
    obj.forEach(function(o) {
      sum += getQte1(o);
    });
    return sum;
  }

  // else it's an object

  var sum = 0;
  // if it has the property qte (the array) add the result to sum
  if (obj.qte !== undefined)
    sum += getQte1(obj.qte);
  // if it has the property qte1 (the number) add the result to sum
  if (obj.qte1 !== undefined)
    sum += parseInt(obj.qte1);
  return sum;
}

console.log(getQte1(obj.my_obj));
```

Comment: @Charuka edits are supposed to enhance the code not to worsen it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with some checks for truthyness or if the key is found or if the actual data is an object - then call the function again.

It works for any depth.

```js
function getSum(object, key) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (s, k) {
        if (!object[k]) {
            return s;
        }
        if (k === key) {
            return s + +object[k];
        }
        if (typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            return s + getSum(object[k], key);
        }
        return s;
    }, 0);

};

var data = { my_obj: [{ qte: [{ qte1: "2", somthing: "toto" }, { qte1: "1", somthing: "tata" }] }, { qte: [{ qte1: "77" }, { somthing: "titi" }] }] },
    sum = getSum(data, 'qte1');

console.log(sum);
```